# VB Calculator add some functions

Tags: vb.net, winforms, calculator

I have programmed a calculator with Visual Basic, but I would like to add a few more functions. But I can't figure out how to solve the following problems in my code:

1. if more than one zero is entered in the input field, it should simply delete the leading zeros.(example 0000111 -----> 111 or 0002345 ----> 2345)
2. likewise, a decimal number should not have several zeros before the decimal point (example 000.176 ----> 0.176)
3. furthermore, it should not be possible to enter two commas (Example 0.187.56 -----> should not be Possible -------------> 0.18756)
   Could somebody help me ?

```
Public Class Form1
    Public LCD As Single
    Public OPZ As String

    Private Sub LCDfuellen(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click, btn2.Click, btn1.Click, btn9.Click, btn8.Click, btn7.Click, btn6.Click, btn5.Click, btn4.Click
        txtLCD.Text &= ActiveControl.Tag

        Replace(LTrim(Replace(txtLCD.Text, "0", " ")), " ", "0")

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtLCD.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCE.Click
        'txtLCD.Text = txtLCD.Text.Remove(txtLCD.TextLength - 1, 1)
        txtLCD.Text = LSet(txtLCD.Text, txtLCD.TextLength - 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub OPZlesen(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlus.Click, btnMinus.Click, btnMal.Click, btnDurch.Click
        LCD = CSng(txtLCD.Text)
        txtLCD.Clear()
        OPZ = ActiveControl.Tag



    End Sub

    Private Sub btnGleich_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGleich.Click
        Dim activeLCD As Single
        activeLCD = CSng(txtLCD.Text)

        Select Case OPZ
            Case "+" : txtLCD.Text = CStr(LCD + activeLCD)
            Case "-" : txtLCD.Text = CStr(LCD - activeLCD)
            Case "*" : txtLCD.Text = CStr(LCD * activeLCD)
            Case "/" : txtLCD.Text = CStr(LCD / activeLCD)
        End Select
    End Sub



    Private Sub btn0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn0.Click

        txtLCD.Text &= ActiveControl.Tag

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPunkt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPunkt.Click

        txtLCD.Text &= ActiveControl.Tag
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Why allow any leading zeroes? Have you ever seen an electronic calculator that does? I haven't.

Comment: sorry i misspelled, of course i mean it should not have a zero before a number

Comment: If you simply call `ToString` on a numeric value then it will not display leading zeroes.

Comment: You can validate the user input with Decimal.TryParse. The output from TryParse should meet each criteria you defined (1-3).